# How to open a VxWorks project using PROFILE_BOOTAPP Configuration profile

Tags: vxworks

I am trying to create a custom boot loader in vxworks. When I try to open a project with configuration profile "PROFILE_BOOTAPP". There is no such option. Has anyone faced a similar situation??

Answer (score 0):

If during the project creation the PROFILE_BOOTAPP option is not available, it's most likely because you based the project on a SMP Source Build. Redo the VSB with Uniprocessor (UP) and try again.